# Docker Volumes running in alphabetical order instead of the order I placed them

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
        logging:
          options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes:
          - ./A.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/A.sql
          - ./B.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/B.sql
          - ./D.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/D.sql
          - ./C.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/C.sql
```

I have the files in the Volumes placed like this so that A will be run first, B second, D third, and C last. However, when I run docker-compose up, it's running the files in alphabetical order as opposed to the order I placed them in. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the files, so they have names inside the container that'll cause them to be executed in the order you want. Like this

```
volumes:
  - ./A.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/A.sql
  - ./B.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/B.sql
  - ./D.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/C.sql
  - ./C.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/D.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The docker postgres image runs the initialization scripts in alphabetical order:

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.
>
> [...]
>
> These initialization files will be **executed in sorted name order** as defined by the current locale, which defaults to en_US.utf8. Any *.sql files will be executed by POSTGRES_USER, which defaults to the postgres superuser. It is recommended that any psql commands that are run inside of a *.sh script be executed as POSTGRES_USER by using the --username "$POSTGRES_USER" flag. This user will be able to connect without a password due to the presence of trust authentication for Unix socket connections made inside the container.

[Source.](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

If you wish to change the order, you must change the names of the files. The order that they are mounted into the container is ignored.